# SAS attrn not returning correct number of observations

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am working in SAS Enterprise guide on a line of code that is supposed to read the number of observations in a dataset. The dataset contains 3 rows (observations).

I write the following line of code to get the number of observations and store it in the `number_observations` variable:

```
call symputx("number_observations", put(attrn(dsid, "nobs"),best.));
```

However, instead of getting a result of `3`, this line returns `9` for me

Any idea what is happening? I should maybe also note that I manually edited this table (it used to have 9 rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nlobs` instead of `nobs`. `nlobs` gives the number of logical observations, honoring any records marked for deletion.

There are some situations where nlobs will return -1 if it doesn't know the number of observations. My favorite countobs paper is http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi26/p095-26.pdf.